# Cypress: How to do a cy.type without a click

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm curious as to why cypress seems to be triggering a click at the beginning of the .type() command. Here's the whole command I'm trying to run:

```
cy.contains(".rt-tr", "Taoh").type("{downarrow}");
```

Unfortunately as you can see in the picture below, this type action seems to trigger a click:
[image: debugger stack of click event being fired when the cy.type command is run]

I can potentially understand why that might make sense in order to bring that element into focus, but what about if that element IS already focused.

I tried doing

```
cy.contains(".rt-tr", "Taoh").click().type("{downarrow}");
```

And it seems to trigger 2 click events. This is confusing to me. Any way to avoid that click would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about you use `.focus` first before type `cy.contains(".rt-tr", "Taoh").focus().type("{downarrow}");`

Comment: That did indeed do it @AlapanDas. That particular element wasn't focus-able but one of its containing elements above was and that seemed to prevent the click from occurring. Cheers!

Comment: Hey happy that you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op was able to solve it by adding `.focus`

```js
cy.contains(".rt-tr", "Taoh").focus().type("{downarrow}")
```